# Redirect to Login page from Global.asax Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I have a callback method which loads only custom user control inside a container control, I'm using form authentication inside my pages, and store the user authentication information inside my page user identity, `Page.User.Identity`
I also store the page user information using `Global.asax` events:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
         //Get Forms Identity From Current User
    } 
    else 
    {
         //redirect to login.aspx page
    }
}
```

Now when I call that callback method and user is not authenticated the callback doesn’t fire, but the only peace of code that’s fire inside the `global.asax` previous event.
From that event I need to redirect to `login.aspx` page, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", true); ` ?

Comment: I guess it is better to create custome attirubbute like CustomeAuthorizeAttribute inherit from AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", true); Is not working :(

Comment: It work for sure, something else is not working to you.

Comment: The request came from a callback request, i guess that's why it's not working ..

Comment: I need something like RedirectOnCallBack in DevExpress !!

Comment: anyway i found this solution here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1165851.aspx But i dont know how to implement it!